# Multipler delimiters in a column

Tags: r, string, dataframe, tidyr, delimiter

Column of results with multiple answers separated by `','` or `'/'`. Need to count the instances of each response.

[image: what the data looks like]

What I want to end up with is

[image: what the end should look like]

I'm at a loss how to split the Answers column in the first table. I'm terrible with string splits.

I've tried using both strsplit and str_split as part of the data frame and turning the column into a list and trying them that way, but it was messy and keep giving me various error messages. I'm close with

```
df %>% separate_longer_delim(Answers, delim = ',/')
```

But I can't get the `delim` part to work. I can use either the comma or the slash but not both together.

Comment: Where do you find the `separate_longer_delim()` function, tidyr? For some reason I cannot find it even after updating the package. I thought maybe you need to use `separate_longer_delim(Answers,delim=c(',','/')` but without the function for testing I can't test

Comment: @dandrews you need to update to `tidyr v1.3.0`.

Comment: @DarrenTsai I just did...must be having errors with the update thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the document of [`separate_longer_delim`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_longer_delim.html):

> `delim`: By default, it is interpreted as a fixed string; use [`stringr::regex()`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/modifiers.html) and friends to split in other ways.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  separate_longer_delim(Answers, stringr::regex("[,/]\\s*")) %>%
  count(Answers, sort = TRUE)

#          Answers n
# 1           cars 2
# 2           dirt 2
# 3           toys 2
# 4 all the things 1
# 5          dolls 1
# 6         trucks 1
```

###### Data

```r
df <- data.frame(id = 1:4, Answers = c("toys, dirt", "cars, dolls", "cars/toys/dirt", "all the things, trucks"))
```